# how can I turn off 'allow hybrid sleep' in advanced power setting? by c#

Tags: c#

how can I turn off 'allow hybrid sleep' in advanced power setting? by c#
by manually: power options -> change Plan Settings -> change advanced power setting-> 
Sleep-> 'Allow hybrid sleep' ->  plugged in: OFF

Comment: Keep in mind that "Hybrid Sleep" is just "Sleep" in Windows 7.

Comment: @Polynomial, do you sure? I use with win7 OS,And so it seems 'Allow hybrid sleep'

Comment: Yes, the power option is there, but when you actually hit the "Sleep" button, it'll either do normal or hybrid sleep depending on that power option.

Comment: This is best done with group policy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are targeting Windows 7/2008 Server then you can use WMI and the [Win32_PowerSetting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd904532%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) class. Below is code that does that. Make sure to add an assembly reference and `using` directive to `System.Management`.

```
    private bool SetAllowHybridSleep(bool enabled)
    {
        //Machine to work on, "." for local
        string RemotePC = ".";

        //Set the namespace to the power namespace, used throughout the function
        ManagementScope ms = new ManagementScope(@"\\" + RemotePC + @"\root\cimv2\power");

        //Will hold each of our queries
        ObjectQuery oq = null;

        //Will hold the values of our power plan and the specific setting that we want to change
        Guid PowerPlanInstanceId = Guid.Empty;
        string PowerSettingInstanceId = null;

        //Look for the specific setting that we want
        oq = new ObjectQuery(string.Format("SELECT * FROM Win32_PowerSetting WHERE ElementName = 'Allow hybrid sleep'"));
        using (ManagementObjectSearcher mos = new ManagementObjectSearcher(ms, oq))
        {
            ManagementObjectCollection results = mos.Get();
            foreach (ManagementObject obj in results)
            {
                foreach (PropertyData p in obj.Properties)
                {
                    if (p.Name == "InstanceID")
                    {
                        //This will give us a string with a GUID specific to our setting
                        PowerSettingInstanceId = p.Value.ToString();
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        //Sanity check
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(PowerSettingInstanceId))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("System does not support hybrid sleep");
            return false;
        }

        //Look for the active power scheme
        oq = new ObjectQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_PowerPlan WHERE IsActive=True");
        using (ManagementObjectSearcher mos = new ManagementObjectSearcher(ms, oq))
        {
            ManagementObjectCollection results = mos.Get();
            foreach (ManagementObject obj in results)
            {
                foreach (PropertyData p in obj.Properties)
                {
                    if (p.Name == "InstanceID")
                    {
                        //The instance contains a string with a GUID inside of it, use the code below to get the GUID by itself
                        if (!Guid.TryParse(System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Match(p.Value.ToString(), @"\{[0-9a-f]{8}\-[0-9a-f]{4}\-[0-9a-f]{4}\-[0-9a-f]{4}\-[0-9a-f]{12}\}").Value, out PowerPlanInstanceId))
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Could not find active power plan");
                            return false;
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        //Now we need to update the actual power setting in the active plan
        //Get all power schemes for the target setting
        oq = new ObjectQuery(string.Format("ASSOCIATORS OF {{Win32_PowerSetting.InstanceID=\"{0}\"}} WHERE ResultClass = Win32_PowerSettingDataIndex", PowerSettingInstanceId.Replace(@"\", @"\\")));
        using (ManagementObjectSearcher mos = new ManagementObjectSearcher(ms, oq))
        {
            ManagementObjectCollection results = mos.Get();
            foreach (ManagementObject obj in results)
            {
                foreach (PropertyData p in obj.Properties)
                {
                    //See if the current scheme is the current setting. This will happen twice, once for AC and once for DC
                    if (p.Name == "InstanceID" && p.Value.ToString().Contains(PowerPlanInstanceId.ToString()))
                    {
                        //Change the value of the current setting
                        obj.SetPropertyValue("SettingIndexValue", (enabled ? "1" : "0"));
                        obj.Put();
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Using procmon, I managed to work out that the following registry key is responsible for it on my machine.

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Power\PowerSettings\238C9FA8-0AAD-41ED-83F4-97BE242C8F20\94ac6d29-73ce-41a6-809f-6363ba21b47e

You'll probably have to do some research on your machine to see how it works for you.

You can also call on the powercfg utility to do this. Each power setting is identified by three things:

1. GUID of power profile
2. GUID of profile subgroup
3. GUID of setting

You can use `powercfg -QUERY` to produce a full list of values.

Once you've got the GUID of the profile you want to edit, the GUID of the subgroup (in this case the Sleep subgroup) and the GUID of the setting (Allow Hybrid Sleep) you can use either `powercfg -SETACVALUEINDEX` for plugged in or `powercfg -SETDCVALUEINDEX` for on battery to set the value.

In my case (Win7 Ultimate x64) you can turn it off using:
`powercfg -SETACVALUEINDEX 381b4222-f694-41f0-9685-ff5bb260df2e 238c9fa8-0aad-41ed-83f4-97be242c8f20 94ac6d29-73ce-41a6-809f-6363ba21b47e 1`

This translates to the AcSettingIndex value in:
`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Power\PowerSettings\238C9FA8-0AAD-41ED-83F4-97BE242C8F20\94AC6D29-73CE-41A6-809F-6363BA21B47E\DefaultPowerSchemeValues\381b4222-f694-41f0-9685-ff5bb260df2e`

Comment: Regardless, manipulating the registry entry or using powercfg will do the job.

Comment: the power management api is the correct approach to the question as asked but group policy sounds more effective

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - I tend to reverse engineer everything just for the sake of it ;)

Comment: You understand why this is a poor approach though I presume. In future windows when they change the location of the key, it breaks. And how do you know it works in all cases in this version. Call the api and let it do the heavy lifting.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - Of course. I haven't touched the power management API, so I figured I'd work out how control panel and powercfg did it. Care to post an answer detailing how it can be done with the power management API?

Comment: The problem is you don't know how it all works. You just have it figured out on your machine. What about a different machine with a different profile selected? I can think of many other flaws here. This is poor advice.

Comment: Thanks, you've saved me SO much Spading @Polynomial!  I cannot thank you enough!  We've been having a lot of troubles with my corp laptop keeps enabling Hybrid sleep, and no matter how we change it through GUI, or the CLI options it keeps coming back after a reboot.  Most baffling off all is "PowerCFG" has absolutely no effect on the hybrid sleep mode when run to turn it on or off, only the GUI method of changing the power options makes the change effective, but again only until reboot.  I've combed through RSOP and our GPOs but can;t find any reason for it.  This will help find the issue! :)

Comment: @Polynomial - I can't thank you enough, I don't know why i didn't think to use the PowerCFG command to get to the actual registry settings this way, it's actually one of those annoying things about MS, they that stupid PowerCFG to edit the reg, but initially you still have to know the GUIDS (they have aliases though now which is nice).  I remember years ago in Windows XP having to get 3rd party utilities or edit this crap by hand so sure powerCFG is kinda nicer, but all you really need is a key and the reg becomes easier to address and diagnose, better than relying on an exe for sure. Thanks!

Comment: @DavidHefferman.  While you have a point about the GUIDs having a possibility of changing in the future, it would break PowerCFG, as the technical way of using it is to use the CLSID s fro the registry, they put in aliases, but most documentation including technet notes the CLSIDS because the utility is just designed to be a quick-hack work around to editing the registry yourself or having others create similar exes which play with the reg but might harbor malicious code.  On many occasions MS breaks these EXE Utilities it releases and you need to be aware of the reg to fix when that happens.

Comment: By the way, it appears the issue with the laptop was not due to the default settings that PowerCFG sets, they were all set to 0s, it looks like it had to do with the copies of the power profiles themselves under "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Power\User\PowerSchemes\"  While "Balanced" (8c5e7fda-e8bf-4a96-9a85-a6e23a8c635c) had the Hybrid Sleep right, Performance (8c5e7fda-e8bf-4a96-9a85-a6e23a8c635c) and Powersaver (a1841308-3541-4fab-bc81-f71556f20b4a) did not have Hybrid Sleep (\238c9fa8-0aad-41ed-83f4-97be242c8f20\94ac6d29-73ce-41a6-809f-6363ba21b47e) Disabled!

Comment: Hybrid sleep stops Hibernate from being an option in the shutdown Menu on the start menu and only allows sleep.  VERY FRUSTRATING!  Now that we have forced the profiles to change to Hybrid sleep off I'm changing the permissions to them to make sure nothing else can change them except specific users.  This was a real pain, but you provided the key that turned the soup of the registry  into a crystal clear set of relationships, and I really really appreciate it :)

Comment: Glad I was some help :)

Comment: With GUID aliases, you can use these more readable commands (turn off hybrid sleep in the balanced power profile):
`powercfg /SETACVALUEINDEX SCHEME_BALANCED SUB_SLEEP HYBRIDSLEEP 0`
`powercfg /SETDCVALUEINDEX SCHEME_BALANCED SUB_SLEEP HYBRIDSLEEP 0`